# Why isn't this method assigning the variable as expected?

Tags: python, methods

I have a method to read from a file and assign the contents to a variable.

```
def recall_data(self, file, d):
    try:
        with open(file) as f:
            d = json.load(f)
            print(d)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('No File!')
```

I call the method and know that the value of d is assigned to the contents of the file (a dictionary). However, the code doesn't store the value of d in the variable I pass as d.

```
self.recall_data(self.file_name, self.data)
```

This is my method call. self.data is an empty dictionary. I don't understand why it isn't assigning self.data with the contents of self.file_name.

Comment: What's the output when you `print(d)`? `d` should point to some dict returned by `json.load` at that point. However, remember that the name `d` is lost when the method returns, so that might be the problem here if you expected `d` to persist.

Comment: `d` is just a local variable here - assigning to it has absolutely no effect outside of the function.  To get a value out of a function, `return` it.

Comment: Try `|=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren't passing the argument for reference.

That's how the argument passage for value works in Python:

```
var = 'hey'
def foo(arg):
    arg = 'yay'
    print(arg)
foo(var) # 'yay'
print(var) # 'hey'
```

---

In your case, you can do this:

```
def recall_data(self, file, d: list): # d is a list with one element
try:
    with open(file) as f:
        d[0] = json.load(f) # This way you are really editing the variable in the global scope
        print(d[0])
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('No File!')
```

Notice that the `d` argument in this case MUST be of type `list`, so `self.data` must too.

If you want to know more about this method, you can read the answers to [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

---

Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
def recall_data(self, file, d):
try:
    with open(file) as f:
        d = json.load(f)
        print(d)
        return d
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('No File!')

self.data = self.recall_data(self.file_name, self.data) # The returned value will be stored into self.data
```

---

Notice that you should never use the first way I suggested above, it was just to solve the problem without changin so much your code.